# Is it possible to build a real-world private ethereum blockchain without any transaction fee and what other costs should I be aware of?

Tags: private-blockchain, dapps

Recently I have been working on a class project. I have built a Supply chain Dapp, that was based on truffle framework and ganache as a local blockchain. I have some issues regarding the concepts of  private Ethreum blockchain.

My question is, is it possible to build a real-world private Ethereum blockchain for a specific organization without any transaction fees and what other costs should I be aware of? And the second question is do I need to deploy my Dapp on Rinkeby?

I found some answers online but they were not satisfactory, it would be greatly appreciated and helpful if you could provide me with some directions on the subject, as I am relatively new to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own testnet would allow for a layer 2-like off-chain blockchain experience. You'd distribute access privileges to participants in the form of an RPC server log-in. Otherwise, build a dapp that interfaces with Rinkeby. Not sure if you could restrict other users, but who'd want to trespass anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are tools for it. Private blockchain networks likes of `Hyperleger Besu` or `Quorum` .